# How to link C library in Ruby extension

Tags: c, ruby, libpng

I'm building a relatively simple C extension to count pixels in a PNG file using libpng; I built the original version in C and it compiles (and works) fine in Cygwin with the command:

> gcc -o shadow_counter shadow_counter.c -lpng

If I don't include the "-lpng" command it won't compile and kicks out a bunch of errors when trying to read the libpng functions ("undefined reference to `png_sig_cmp' ", etc.)

In order to package it for ruby, I put together the gemspec and files and folders and build it into a gem:

> gem build shadow_png.gemspec

Then I head over to Powershell and install the gem:

> gem install shadow_png-0.0.1.gem

If I leave out the libpng stuff, it installs fine and talks to Ruby the way it's supposed to.  But once I start trying to reference the libpng functions and try to install it, it starts kicking out the SAME errors that I saw above (undefined reference to `png_sig_cmp' etc.).  So my theory is that somehow the linking command -lpng isn't included.

How do I include these instructions as part of the process?  Is it something I need to add to the gemspec?  Or the command to build the gem?  Or does it have to happen in the gem installation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for the [have_library](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/mkmf/rdoc/MakeMakefile.html#method-i-have_library) method, to be placed in your `extconf.rb` file.

i.e.

```
abort 'Missing PNG library.' unless have_library('png')
```

Comment: I think that's some forward progress...with that added I get the following error when installing the gem:


`checking for main() in -lpng... no
Missing PNG library.`

Does that mean I need to require libpng somewhere in the extconf.rb files?

Comment: I'm not sure what library function is a good entry point to the library, but I would assume you could use `have_library('png', 'func_name')` with whatever function you're using... If this doesn't work, you might consider manually editing the linker flags using either `LDLIBS` or `LDFLAGS`. [Here's an example](https://github.com/boazsegev/iodine/blob/306f6b5b24b718693d5368e3ecb8a7575e51a732/ext/iodine/extconf.rb#L11-L37) for editing the environment (in the example a complier is chosen).